# Why the dropdown elements gets shifted to left on hovering on each row?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I created a dropdown list using the selectMenu widget of the jQueryUI as shown in the below image:

[image]

Given below is the HTML code for this.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Custom Rendering</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="options">Select an Option:</label>
    <select id="options">
  <optgroup label="PREFERRED OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="L" data-price="$0.00">Standard Screw Adjustment</option>
    <option data-short="K" data-price="$0.00">Standard Screw Adjustment</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="STANDARD OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="C" data-price="$5.00" >Tamper Resistant - Factory Set</option>
    <option data-short="K" data-price="$6.00" >Handknob</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ADDITIONAL OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="F" data-price="-$4.00">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
    <option data-short="G" data-price="$4.00">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
    <option data-short="H" data-price="$4.00" >Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS for this widget.

```
.ui-selectmenu-category {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  padding: 0.5em 0.25em;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2px;
}

.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
}
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item .ui-icon {
  height: 24px;
  width: 14px;
  top: 0.1em;
}


.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  background-color: #e4ebf1;
  color: #000;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active.short {
  color: #2e6d99;
}

.ui-menu-item div.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  width: 290px;
}

.ui-menu-item .short {
  color: #2e6d99;
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 30px;
  padding-left: 0.5em;

}

.ui-menu-item .price {
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: -6px;

}


.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Given below is the Javascript code for this.

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.mySelectMenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li, name, short, price;
        if (item.optgroup != currentCategory) {
          ul.append(
            "<li class='ui-selectmenu-category'>" +
              item.optgroup +
              "</li>"
          );
          currentCategory = item.optgroup;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        console.log(ul);
        name = li.text();
        short = item.element.data("short");
        price = item.element.data("price");
        console.log(li, short, price);
        li.prepend(
          $("<span>", {
            class: "short"
          }).html(short)
        );

        li.append(
          $("<span>", {
            class: "price"
          }).html(price)
        );
        if (item.optgroup) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.optgroup + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $("#options").mySelectMenu({
    width: 300
  });
  $("#options")
    .mySelectMenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("overflow");
});
```

Now, my problem is that whenever I am hovering the cursor on any row, then the elements of that hovered row gets selected to its right. But I want my elements to be fixed in the position. I know that the problem is related to the `.ui-state-active` class. I've tried a lot of tricks whatever I know but none of them has worked out for me. I'm a beginner in CSS. Please help.Mentioned below is the image describing how these elements are shifted.

[image]

Can anyone provide any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try changing the border to an outline.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code or create some similar sample on Plunker? For example, who calls `_renderMenu` ? That's just one example. Please provide a working example of your problem.

Comment: @Chris, I've provided all the code in the question details. Here is the working example of my code in the Codepen: https://codepen.io/DG4/pen/RjzyJv

Comment: thanks for the live code. That made it way easier to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `css` file you need to add a margin of 0 in your `.ui-state-active` class. The hover is causing a margin of -1 to appear. After that you will need to stop it from jumping when you hover up and down. To do this you can remove all of the border properties, and add the `outline: 1px solid #ccc` property. Replacing your current `.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active` block with the one here should fix your issues (at least they did in your codepen)

```
.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  //border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  margin: 0;
  //border-color: #cccccc;
  border: none;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #e4ebf1;
  color: #000;
}
```

To fix the width for higher resolutions you can add a `min-width` property to `.ui-selectmenu-category`

```
.ui-selectmenu-category {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  padding: 0.5em 0.25em;
  min-width: 290px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not working. Adding what you said caused the price column to shift on the bottom on hovering. But that's not what is desired. On hovering, the position of the elements of each row should be fixed.

Comment: Perhaps you simply need to make the width a bit larger. It's working for me? I have added a picture of it working for me. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the vertical line segment which is appearing at the end of each column. For e.g.: between L and Standard Screw Adjustment and $0.00. I just need the horizontal outline/border and not the vertical one. How to do that?

Comment: So the problem is that you're using a higher resolution than I was.

Comment: I added `min-width: 290px;` to `.ui-selectmenu-category` and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: For your other question (no vertical borders), outline will not do that. It's all or none. The benefit of outline is that it doesn't jerk around when you hover up and down. There is a way to achieve this with borders such that you create a transparent border when you're not hovering and then give it color when you hover. That works for some cases but I haven't had the best luck with it. I personally prefer the outline approach. You could certainly try a transparent border though, if you really want to avoid having vertical border lines.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and will let you know if I've any further doubts.

Comment: can you suggest how to make the each row of the dropdown list responsive? I reduced the browser width and then observed that the elements were presented in a weird manner.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? Perhaps update the question with the **UPDATE** keyword. Screenshots and live code are, of course, extremely helpful.